# Not able to click on the element inside the div tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am not able to click on the Public button.

I Have tried below code and getting error message as

> no such element: Unable to locate element:

```
WebElement el2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'title') and text()='Public']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor2.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el2);
```

Please find attached screenshot.

Comment: search the forum the question has been answered multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things that may be causing the no such element exception:

1. The css value for the element might have `text-transform: capitalize`. If this is the case, then you're XPath won't be able to find `text()='Public'` if the actual text value in the html is 'public'. Try it with `text()='public'`, or perhaps look into a non-case-sensitive approach.
2. The page has not fully loaded. Try stepping through the code slowly using a debugger (allowing lots of time for the page to load). If it's as simple as a timing thing, then you can add a WebDriver wait in before finding the element.

Comment: Can you please share some info what is exceptional about `text-transform: capitalize`. Thanks

Comment: It will capitalize the word on the web page but not in the DOM. So WebDriver will be looking for 'Public' (because that's what the developer see's on the web page), but the DOM will contain 'public' (because css doesn't modify the DOM, only the web page).

Comment: Thanks Stewart for the info, I have tried with text()='public' and still issue exist.